# The correct way to typeset comma between math symbols?

Tags: math-mode

I am curious which is the textbook correct way of typing $a,b\in X$ to say that a, b are elements in the set X.

Clearly, the most convenient way is $a,b\in X$.

Qn 1) $a, b\in X$ (note the space between) produces the same thing right?

Other variants I can think of are $a$, $b\in X$, $a$, $b$$\in X$.

Qn 2) Which is the "correct" way?

Comment: Either `$a,b\in X$` or `$a$,~$b\in X$`. Be consistent.

Comment: There was a question exactly like this not long ago. For that situation I almost without doubt would take the first version `$a, b \in X$`.

Comment: q1.  yes `$a,b$` will produce the same output as `$a, b$`.

Comment: +1 for egreg's answer. The comma in the example is not a math comma, it is an ordinary enumeration and should not be included in math mode.

Comment: (Please read this comment with a bit of sense of humor.)  The correct way to type it is `$(a,b)\in X\times X$`. ;-)